# Need PHP pregmach Regexp pattern for string until "|||" characters appears

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have PHP variable that contains string like:

```
http://domain.com/uploads/image1.jpg|||http://domain.com/uploads/image2.jpg|||http://domain.com/uploads/image3.jpg|||...
```

I need to get first one image url from that string, so it will be string until first "|||" characters. So result i need to get into variable is: http://domain.com/uploads/image1.jpg

Please help me to write correct PHP preg_match regexp pattern for it.

Thank you!
Tim

Comment: Tim... as a new user let me encourage you to accept (checking the 'V' mark) the answer that helped you! Happy coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
'/(.*?)\|\|\|/'
```

---

You could also use `expode`:

```
$result = explode('|||', $s, 2);
echo $result[0];
```

Result:

```
http://domain.com/uploads/image1.jpg
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/qfzfX)

Comment: Kids are looking forward @James! ;)

Comment: Mark, great idea to explode! Everything work well! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substr`:

```
$pos = strpos($str, "|||");
$firstUrl = substr($myString, 0, $pos ? $pos : strlen($myString));
```

http://ideone.com/LaudF

Comment: nice one mini! +1 your answer!

Comment: Thanks for solution, haven't tried it but probably it works as well! Thank you.